# Error when click "Edit page" in top menu of Publishing Content Page Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, publishing-page

I have a Publishing Content Page Sharepoint 2013, and whenever I clicked "Edit page" button, this error is thrown:

[image]
[image]

Does anybody knows the cause of this issue, and the solution to solve it?
Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried opening the web part maintenance page? Open by adding ?contents=1 to the end of the URL.

Comment: @GeorgeGrainger yes, I did, and no errors happened ...

Comment: anyone knows the issues, pls answer me asap ... TY